# VS Code use alias from ~/.bashrc in task.json

Tags: visual-studio-code

I alias the path of my cross compiler in my linux system. Now I want use that alias in my `task.json` of VS Code.
So I write this snippet:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Test",
            "type": "shell",
            "linux": {
                "command": "My_gcc"
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

But I got this

`Error 127: Command "My_gcc" not found`

Why do I get this error?

Comment: Where is this alias defined? Almost certainly the context in which this command is invoked has not first loaded the aliases. You probably need to figure out how to have this invocation source the appropriate file so that the shell it invokes has the aliases.

Comment: Hello,

I define the alias in my bashrc-file.
If I change the command to "command": "cat ~/.bashrc" I got the correct output with my defined alias

Comment: That file is probably only read for a login shell, and whatever VS is doing is probably not a login shell. This is probably better researched over on Unix & Linux SE.

Answer (score 3):

Just alter your task as follows:
    `"command": "source ~/.bash_profile && My_gcc"`

This will make it source ~/.bash_profile into scope before trying to use your alias.